# Problem with SQL query [Inner join and multiple selects]

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, inner-join

here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT messages.*, 
   users.* 
   FROM `afo_messages` as messages 
   INNER JOIN `key_users` as users ON messages.user_id = users.id 
   WHERE messages.category_id=5 
   ORDER BY messages.id DESC LIMIT 30) ilv 
ORDER BY messages.id ASC
```

Error is "#1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'".

Table afo_messages columns:

```
id | user_id | category_id | parent_id | message | create_date | update_date | status
```

Table key_users columns:

```
id | name | email | phone | pwd | active | role | invite_id | download_link | date
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure that when you run the inner query, the result set has two columns called ID (on from messages, one from users); you're then running a query on that subquery, and the parser doesn't understand it.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT messages.id as message_id,
       messages.user_id, 
       ....all other columns from messages

       users.id as real_user_id, 
       users.name, 
       ..... all other columns from users
FROM `afo_messages` as messages 
INNER JOIN `key_users` as users ON messages.user_id = users.id 
WHERE messages.category_id=5 
ORDER BY messages.id DESC LIMIT 30) ilv 
ORDER BY message_id ASC
```

Comment: It's ilmost right, but i gor error: #1054 - Unknown column 'messages.id' in 'order clause'. I think it because of this ORDER BY messages.id ASC

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting two columns called `ID` without aliasing one.  Do you really need ALL of the columns from both tables.  This is generally bad practice.  You would probably be better off specifying exactly which columns you want and aliasing one of the `ID`s.  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT messages.ID,  
    messages.message, 
    users.id as UserId, --aliasing this column to UserId
    users.name, 
    users.email
   FROM `afo_messages` as messages 
   INNER JOIN `key_users` as users ON messages.user_id = users.id 
   WHERE messages.category_id=5 
   ORDER BY messages.id DESC LIMIT 30) ilv 
ORDER BY messages.id ASC
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'messages.id' in 'order clause'

Comment: you can't do the slightest of troubleshooting to determine what the problem might be there?

Answer (score 0):

Your internal query says `SELECT messages.*, users.*...` and both `afo_messages` and `key_users` have an `id` field. Pick one, or alias them.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `id` columns, one in each table. You need to not use `SELECT *` and alias at least one of them to give it a distinct name.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT messages.id AS messageid, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't match the error message, but shouldn't your final ORDER BY be by ilv.id?

In the context of your outer query, no table named "message" was ever referenced.